# Developing Android app using .html file

Tags: android

I imported .html file into android application (assets/www/.html). Now i tried to access that data to my app as `webview.loadUrl("file://android_assets/www/index.html");`. But while running it in eclipse, Emulator is showing "webpage not available ". Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: Could it be that the file must be referenced locally? Maybe try it without "file:///" at all - just try "/android_assets/www/index.html" or "android_assets/www/index.html".

Answer (score 2):

i guess you need to use `file:///android_asset` instead of `file://android_assets` in your file path.

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: did you use three slashes instead of two? check my updated answer

Comment: I tried three slashes too.But it is not working.Any more suggestions?

Comment: try putting your html file in root (without www folder) and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the solution to your problem. But maybe your application doesn't work because it tries to find a url in the internet instead of a file name. You should try uploading your file and change the location to http://... .

Comment: Where should i upload my file? I already imported to my app "asset/www/index.html".

Comment: It won't look for the file on the web. The URL has the "file://" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); we have to import "jquery.dst.js" into  "assets/www/css-js". css-js" is a folder.

Answer (score 0):

if your using phonegap : you may use :        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Answer (score 0):

try out this may be helpful for you-

```
webview.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```